# installing visual studio 2013 ultimate beside visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, conflict

i have installed visual studio 2010 ultimate edition for some years.

My operating system is windows 7 x64 sp1.

I want to install (visual studio 2013 ultimate edition + Update1) beside visual studio 2010

ultimate edition. I found some links about conflict between vs2010 and vs2012 but they did not

mentioned about conflict between vs2010 and vs2013.

please help if you found any conflicts.

Thanks alot.

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  You cannot get a warranty here.  Just install it, if you find a conflict then ask a specific question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant : thanks but i am afraid of that after installing vs2013 , i have to uninstall every thing and the troubles will come to scene. because i have created and now developing some project and afraid that this upgrade may cause hazard to my projects and makes me to waste my time.